# How to gather input from the user in VS code Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, user-input

So when I run this code, nothing prints onto the "output" screen. Although when I remove`Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` and `String wow = in.next();`, it prints the output `wow`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please Try
wow = in.nextLine();